How to send input file in playwright where input has attribute hidden
I am unable to upload a file using Playwright as it can't find a locator for input type
I'm trying to upload a file as below :
 await page.locator('//div/input[@class=xyz]').setInputFiles('Upload_files/CSV Test file.csv');

but the browser is unable to find this locator as the input type as attribute hidden
<input type="file" class="xyz" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.doc,.docx,.xlsx,.xls,.csv,.pdf" hidden>



Please share the page and a [mcve] of the code. It's hard to automate a site we can't see. Thanks. That said, if the element is on the page, try page.$('...') rather than the locator, which ignores visibility. Avoid XPath--CSS is cleaner: div input.xyz (and even CSS is discouraged if you're testing). Or manipulate the page to make the upload visible as a human would.

What error did you get?

Not sure I really like this, but you could remove the hidden attribute first...
await this.page.evaluate(() => {
    const inputElement = document.querySelector('//div/input[@class=xyz]');
    if (inputElement) {
      inputElement.removeAttribute('hidden');
    }
});


I have had luck finally figured this out:
You don't try to find the input. You try to wait for the file chooser to show.
I have a button#browse that triggers a hidden file input. So this is the code that worked for me:
const fileChooserPromise = page.waitForEvent('filechooser');
await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'browse' }).click();
const fileChooser = await fileChooserPromise;
await fileChooser.setFiles('./tests/fixures/sig_test.png');

Got this from another reply here in stackoverflow: Playwright: Upload files from non-input element that cannot be used page.setInputFiles?

This is what worked for me:
You must update the part below //some[@valid='xpath'] to the valid xpath of the element accepting the file path.
await page.locator("xpath=//some[@valid='xpath']").setInputFiles("C:/path/to/your/file.txt")

Also see the docs: https://playwright.dev/docs/input#upload-files
